# Problems Installing markdown-mode emacs 23.1.1

Tags: emacs, markdown

In trying to install `markdown-mode` on my Emacs 23.1.1 I followed the `README.md` and added the following to my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

Then, I'm supposed to be able to do this:

<kbd>M-x package-install RET markdown-mode RET</kbd>.

However I get a `[No Match]` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run `package-refresh-contents`? Try that before you run `package-install`.

Comment: That advanced things, but I still don't see markdown-mode as an option.

Comment: If you use the interactive UI launched by `package-list-packages` do you see `markdown-mode` listed there?

Comment: No.  I do get a long list of packages, but it is not in it.

Comment: Ah, I should have seen this earlier. I'm adding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`markdown-mode` 2.3](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/rev-2-3), the version [available on MELPA Stable](https://stable.melpa.org/#/markdown-mode), requires Emacs 24.3 or later. [Version 2.1](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/blob/master/CHANGES.md#markdown-mode-21), from January, 2016, looks like it might work with Emacs 23:

> Fix Emacs 23 compatibility by checking for font-lock-refresh-defaults before calling it.

Although, even in that version:

> Markdown Mode is developed and tested primarily for compatibility with GNU Emacs versions 24.3 and later.

You can try installing it manually following the [old installation instructions from version 2.1](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/tree/c6eb56eff31f7961c9a00a5d18eaf939c2c40b7d#installation). Make sure to check out the [`v2.1` tag](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/commit/c6eb56eff31f7961c9a00a5d18eaf939c2c40b7d) after cloning the source!

Comment: Hmm . . . it may be that I must suffer in obsolescence.

Comment: @RaySalemi, I guess there is some external constraint keeping you on Emacs 23.1?